# How do you stop RTC_WAKEUP from being called everytime the phone boots?

Tags: android, android-notifications

In my project, the RTC_WAKEUP method gets called every time the phone boots regardless of what time or date I issued the notification.

My question is, how can I only have the phone issue the notification when the user wants the notification and not automatically on boot?

My long variable timeDateNotification can be found in these inner classes:

```
 public static class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
            implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int minute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

            return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
                    DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
        }

        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, view.getCurrentMinute());
            cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, view.getCurrentHour());
            timeDateNotification = cal.getTimeInMillis();

        }
    }

    public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
            implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Use the current date as the default date in the picker

            int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
        }

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
            cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, view.getYear());
            cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, view.getMonth());
            cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, view.getDayOfMonth());
            timeDateNotification = cal.getTimeInMillis();

        }
    }
```

Here is the method that is causing all the problems.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AlertClass.class);
                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeDateNotification, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity()
                        .getApplicationContext(), 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Notification sent!" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

And here is the AlertClass:

```
    public class AlertClass extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            CreateNotification(context, "Forgetting something?", "Click here for more details", "Alert");
        }

        private void CreateNotification(Context context, String title, String text, String alert) {
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(context, MainActivityTrekkly.class), 0);

            NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setTicker(alert)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(text)
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                    .setAutoCancel(true);

                    notification.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.notify(1, notification.build());

        }
    }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code resolved this problem. Turn off the receiver first then cancel the notification.

```
                ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(getActivity(), AlertClass.class);
                PackageManager pm = getActivity().getPackageManager();
                pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
                        PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                        PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AlertClass.class);
                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                alarmManager.cancel(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity()
                        .getApplicationContext(), 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
```